# c++ visual studio cout returned string

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm new in programming for Windows with C++.

I compiled this code successfully with G++ compiler in Linux and in Windows XP with Mingw compiler.

Code:
[image]

I call this function so:

[image]

But it when I  try to compile it with VS C++ 2010 on Windows  7, I get complain:

[image]

I can't get why it's so. This visual studio is so strange.

Comment: Please paste your actual code and errors, not pictures.

Comment: Did you include the `<string>` header?

Comment: That's a QtCreator screenshot. Are you using the Visual Studio compiler with Qt Creator?

Comment: StackedCrooked, yes, I use QtCreator with Visual Studio, by default Qt Creator is offered with Visual Studio compiler in Windows 7 (and with Mingw compiler in Windows  XP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std` headers can include one another, but it's not mandated which ones should include which. Your safest bet is to have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

at the top of the file.

My guess is the compilers that did compile the code had these headers included indirectly, whereas VS doesn't. Which is fine. The programmer is responsible for including all headers he needs.